# Cable Tester Errors/Cat6 Hookup Questions

Tags: networking, home-networking, cable, cat6, cable-tester

I am new to home networking.  I laid Cat6 cable through my house.  When I use a cable tester (NS-468 from Micro Center), the master will show numbers 1-8 light up in sequence, but the remote will show numbers 8-1 light up in sequence.  So, the remote is counting down instead of counting up.  I cannot get any of the cables to work.

I made the cable myself, and I followed the T568B protocol.

Can you determine from my description what I might have done wrong? 
What should I do to diagnose this problem?

Comment: I am going to assume, you made the cable, if that is the case.  That is very important information which should be in the body of the question.

Comment: Edited.  Thanks.  Hopefully my edit will elicit some responses.

Comment: Do you want to imply that feeding a signal to the yellow pair (1-2) somehow comes out as signal on the brown pair (7-8) at the other end?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that perhaps you took the idea of "1:1 through cabling" too literally: You connected in mirror symmetry as if the wires ran though in a parallel band. Instead, on both sides, the same pin should receive the same wire. For example, viewing the socket<sup>1</sup> from outside with the "nose" thing on top and the contacts at the bottom, pin 1 is the rightmost and should receive the orange-white wire, pin 2 the orang wire, etc.  (if you use the B standard) -- and this holds for both ends.

<sup>1</sup>  Here I *assume* you are wiring socket to socket with the intend of adding patch cables at the end. However, the same argument applies with left-right switched for a plug to plug cable you make.

Comment: Instead of leaving a comment saying this worked, Please mark this answer accepted. That's how this site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The remote counting in reverse may mean the wire is in crossover. If the lights all blink, it means the crossover is working as intended.

[Heres a random screenshot from the interweb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMZq2.png)

Its hard to say exatly, but the principle of these cheap ones does allow crossover testing, according to this guy who goes over the basics of most meter types:

https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/understanding-network-cable-testers/

This may however only apply to the meters in question, says the internet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).